# Audio.play() doesn't work ONLY in if statement

Tags: javascript, if-statement

So I am making a small game to practice javascript. I wanted to add the getting point sound when the car is not crashing with the obstacle. If the car is not crashing with obstacles, I am adding points and making the obstacle disappear and appearing once again at the top of the road so everything is working fine. Under those lines, I added the audio.play(); function and it is not working. I added the alert to check if it should work and the alert is appearing so what is going on?

```
else if(document.getElementById("B7").innerHTML == '<div id="obstacle">X</div>' || document.getElementById("A7").innerHTML == '<div id="obstacle">X</div>')
        {
            document.getElementById("A7").innerHTML = "";
            document.getElementById("B7").innerHTML = "";
            points = points + addPoints;
            audio.play();
            alert("sound here");
            nextObstacle();
        }
```

Link for GitHub repository for this project:

https://github.com/AdamMaichrzik/Spliterio/blob/master/car.html

Lines 270 - 280.

Comment: The sound works fine. Check you audio settings as this should have nothing to do with the application code :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I googled more about this problem and it turns out that some of web browsers are blocking playing sound without previously clicking any button or something like that to play the sound. You HAVE TO first CLICK some button to play the sound and then it can be played in loops etc. So I just added play sound while selecting difficulty and it is working when the car is not crashing.